Reversing characters of string of parenthesis to achieve at max H string depth
Given a integer H and string s which contains only ( and ) characters, and is properly formed (every opening bracket has corresponding closing bracket, the pairs of brackets are properly nested), return an integer indicating minimally how many brackets you need to reverse to achieve valid string which depth is no more than H.
The depth of string in this case is the maximum level of brackets nesting. For example, string (()(())) has depth equal to 3.
Generally, I think we can apply greedy approach - just iterate over string characters and while this process maintain a variable that stores current depth of string. If at any moment it's going to be higher than H, reverse current bracket. Also, in the case when depth is going to be below zero, also reverse the character.
That's code I've written, and it works perfectly fine:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    cout.tie(nullptr);

    int n, H;
    cin >> n >> H;

    string s;
    cin >> s;

    int depth = 0;
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        if (s[i] == '(' && depth == H) {
            s[i] = ')';
            ++ans;
        }
        else if (s[i] == ')' && depth == 0) {
            s[i] = '(';
            ++ans;
        }

        if (s[i] == '(')
            ++depth;
        else
            --depth;
    }

    cout << ans;
}

That was my intuition. But I can't figure out how can I be sure that the final string (after reversing specific characters) will always be valid (parenthess are nested properly etc).
Firstly, at some point, we will come to the case where depth is going to exceed H. This is where we reverse the opening bracket into closing bracket. Assume we did it on index i (while iterating over s). Due to this modification, we will have closing bracket that has no corresponding bracket in future (some index j where j > i). It may happen that depth is below zero after this (so we reverse closing bracket to opening), but it's not necessary (and we will end up with invalid string).
That's where my reasoning ends. For me, it seems invalid, but if the code works, it means I missed something.
So, how can I be sure, that after performing these all operations, I will end up with valid string?

Unrelated, but throw away the first three lines of the main functions. They are just part of a cargo cult that's generally never used in the real world.

Also, please read What's the problem with "using namespace std;"? and please don't do cargo cult stuff like "ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);     cin.tie(nullptr);     cout.tie(nullptr);" that would never pass code review in any professional setting and (unless you really know what you are doing) will just lead to bugs.

But I can't figure out how can I be sure that the final string (after reversing specific characters) will always be valid (parenthess are nested properly etc) -- Run thousands of random test cases with known answers, and then comparing your answers to the known answers.  You're asking us to be your fuzzing engine

@Someprogrammerdude That isn't completely sound advice. On problems with a large amount of input, programs with the intended time complexity can exceed the time limit without those lines to speed up input. There is no benefit to be gained from removing them, though I agree that untying cin isn't all that necessary (and cout isn't tied by default anyway).

@Unmitigated I have never worked on any real world professional software project where the synchronisation of C and C++ input/output streams ever made a difference that actually matteret. But I have worked on code bases where some ass-hat had added things like in OP's code and it caused real bugs that cost real money. It's a "competitive coding" thing that just needs to go away. Sure, it exists for a reason and there are a (few) cases where it can make sense, but that's expert territory and that is clearly not where we are at currently.

@JesperJuhl As long as companies ask technical questions that are watered-down competitive programming questions, this is unlikely to go away. And since this a competitive programming problem, removing those lines doesn't really help (and can actively make a solution worse).

It's simple, really. Once you reached an opening paren at depth H, you need to transform the fragment of the string up to the matching closing paren into )()()...()( since that's the only way to keep the depth at H and no deeper. I think your algorithm does just that, but is formulated in a way that doesn't make this obvious.

@IgorTandetnik "that's the only way" no.

To rephrase the question, I think you are asking for a proof regarding the correctness of your program as opposed to "write a fuzzer" as some comments suggested.
You can think about a valid bracket string this way: For your brack string s of length n, we can represent it using a sequence a. Let ai = +1 if the i-th character is (, and let ai = -1 if the i-th character is ). Now that s is a valid bracket sequence if and only if ∑ i=0 k ai ≥ 0 for 0 ≤ k < n and that ∑ i=0 n-1 ai = 0. (See Catalan Number and Dywk path for more details.)
Thus, changing a ( to a ) is equivalent to changing a +1 to a -1. Therefore, suppose you change al = +1 to al = -1 (( to )), and am = -1 to am = +1 () to () for some l < m, then ∑ i=0 k ai would be unchanged for all k before l and after m. As for the sums between l and m, since your program is essentially looking for the first m where the sum ∑ i=0 m ai becomes negative after you changed ( to ) at l, they are certainly not negative. Therefore, the bracket string produced by your program is always valid.
As for your concern "due to this modification, we will have closing bracket that has no corresponding bracket in future" and "it may happen that depth is below zero after this", this would actually not be an issue. Consider the following example:
( ( ( ) ( ) ) )
Your solution should flip the bold brackets if I want the maximum depth to be 2.
( ( ) ) ( ) ( )
Now note the bold brackets below, previously this is a bracket pair:
( ( ( ) ( ) ) )
But the left most bracket would now pair like this:
( ( ) ) ( ) ( )
Therefore, you needn't worry about what brackets are paired exactly, but just that every closing bracket is paired with some opening bracket.
